# MING files running error

Tags: c, matlab, emma

I am trying to run ADNI .mnc image in MATLAB

I added folder emma-master, niak-0.7.1-ammo, mia and niak-0.7.1-ammo to my path. All these folders are located in

`D:\EMINA BURCH\PhD Thesis\MATLAB Packages`

But when I want to open `._bq_t_15T.mnc` located also in `D:\EMINA BURCH\PhD Thesis\MATLAB Packages`

that is h = openimage('._bq_n_15T.mnc')

I get the following error

> Error using miinquire (line 145)
>   Error getting image dimensions from file D:\EMINA BURCH\PhD Thesis\MATLAB  Packages._bq_n_15T.mnc
>
> Error in openimage (line 173)
>   DimSizes = miinquire (filename, 'imagesize');

When I enter debug mode in minquire function  after the line

```
[stat,out] = system(['mincinfo -vardims image ' minc_file]);
```

I get stat = 1 and out = 'mincinfo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

May You, please help me with this issue.

Comment: Basically you are trying to run a program called `mincinfo` via a system command. This system command is given from matlab. Are you able to run this system command directly? Otherwise this question is hardly matlab related and I would recommend removal of the tag.

Answer (score 0):

`system` isn't able to automatically recognise the different requirements that might be needed to run the same system command on different operating systems.  Using commands like `ispc`, `isunix`, `ismac` and `computer`, you can automatically check and call different versions of the commands as appropriate:

```
if ispc
   [stat,out] = system(['mincinfo.exe -vardims image ' minc_file]);
else
   [stat,out] = system(['mincinfo -vardims image ' minc_file]);
end
```

Of course, you also have to have the appropriate program on your MATLAB path for this to work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I tried this as well, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Do you have the program, `mincinfo`, installed and on your MATLAB path?